# How to stretch div to size of parent li

Tags: css

I have an ul/li where each li contains 2 div. One of the div ("category") can content text that can wrap on multiple lines. I'm trying to get the other div ("abbr") of that li to have the same height. Since the parent li is stretching, I tried height: 100% on the abbr but it doesn't stretch it to.

Any idea?

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="abbr">ABC</div>
    <div class="category">Long or short</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="abbr">ABC</div>
    <div class="category">Very long or very shortshort</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

And the css I used:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
}

div.abbr {
 float: left;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 30px;
 background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

div.category {
/*float: left;*/
padding: 16px;
border: 1px solid red;
margin-left:64px;

}
```

Here's a fiddle if you wanna play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/P6UzU/

Comment: Shouldn't you use a definition list : <DL> ?

Comment: Indeed, it seems you're right... Although I just modified at existing ul/li to add the "abbr" div so if I can avoid changing too much it's better for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use css tables and remove the float:left on the first div

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/P6UzU/2/)**

### CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
    display:table; /* <--- */
}
li
{
   display:table-row;  /* <--- */
}
div.abbr {

 padding: 16px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 30px;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell; /* <--- */
}

div.category {
    /*float: left;*/ /* <--- removed */
    padding: 16px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-left:64px;
    display:table-cell; /* <--- */

}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Was missing display: table-cell when I tried! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS tables as Danield say above, or you can **simulate** the effect you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/P6UzU/3/

I put the blue background and the red border in the `li` tag, and a white background in the "category" class. Also, change the whole border in "category" to a `border-left`.

Comment: You are literally thinking out-of-the-box!

Answer (score 0):

As others have said,

```css
li a { display: block; }
```

should achieve what you’re after. But you must also remove any padding from the `<li>` and set it on the `<a>` instead. For example:

```css
li { padding: 0; }
li a { display: block; padding: 1em; }
```

Comment: Where do you see any `a` tag here?

Answer (score 0):

guys final i get the answer plz chk this....
html code:--

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="abbr">ABC</div>
    <div class="category">Long or short</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="abbr1">ABC</div>
    <div class="category1">Very long or very shortshort & Very long or very shortshort</div>
</li>

</ul>
```

CSS:--

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
}

div.abbr {
 float: left;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 30px;
 background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

div.category {
/*float: left;*/
padding: 16px;
border: 1px solid red;
margin-left:64px;

}
div.abbr1 {
 float: left;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 30px;
 background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

div.category1 {
/*float: left;*/
padding: 16px;
border: 1px solid red;
margin-left:64px;

}
```

Script:--

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var rightHeight = $('.category1').height();

$('.abbr1').css({'height':rightHeight});
```

and to this thing work out you have to add `jquery/1.8.2`..

Demo:--[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salwenikhil0724/P6UzU/8/)

Comment: Not a bad idea in itself, but that would probably make the size "move" around at page load... I'll try the css approach on this

Comment: yes as i am new in this i am getting the answer but not in smart way.may be it will take some time..